# Cairo-Dock Bubble Borders

Tags: debian, xfce, window-manager

I recently installed Cairo-Dock and there is this ugly Bubble border line on all the message Bubbles of Cairo-Dock.

I have tried to configure in Cairo-Dock-Configure through its GUI and by setting the Bubble-border outline to 0 manually by editing the .conf file in the current themes.

I also looked through the settings XFCE Window-Manager but could not find any settings that helped. It seems that the border area is transparent and only the border outline is black.

Is there a way to get rid of those border-outlines?

[image]

Comment: More important is that the most bottom row is cutted off - and I find no setting to fix this! Bubble, modern and every setting is too small and cutting off the bottom row of text